# Power BI - Creating a measure as a Visual Level Filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a requirement, where I have data like this.

```
ColA ColB ColC ColD
A    A     C    1 
B    C     C    1
A    B     C    3
C    D     C    2
```

I have one visual as a table with just Col A and Col B generated through the Min Number on Col D.

```
ColA ColB  
A    A     
B    c
```

I want to generate another visual table that takes these ColA Values "A" and "B" and filters the actual data table.

```
  ColA ColB ColC ColD
    A    A     C    1 
    B    C     C    1
    A    B     C    3
```

I am trying to solve this using `AllSelected` Function but it is not helping me. How can we use a measure on a visual level filter to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filtering measure like this:

```
FilterMeasure = 
    VAR MinD = CALCULATE(MIN(Table2[ColD]), ALLSELECTED(Table2))
    VAR AVals = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Table2[ColA]),
                    ALLSELECTED(Table2),
                    Table2[ColD] = MinD)
    RETURN IF(MAX(Table2[ColA]) IN AVals, 1, 0)
```

First, it finds the minimal number in `ColD`. Then it finds the values in `ColA` that are associated with that `ColD` value. Finally, it returns `1` if the `ColA` value in the row of your table visual is one of the ones from the previous step and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Can you help me with this one please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693457/power-bi-measure-to-calculate-the-distinct-count