# Power BI - Measure to calculate the distinct count

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a requirement where I am calculating the distinct count while leaving a particular value.

For example,

*Consider this -*

```
BU    Rev     RevDes   concatenatedcolumnfordistinctcount
1A     AppR      1A           1AAppR1A
1A     AppR      2A           1AAppR2A
1A     FAppR     3A           1AFAppR3A
2A     BcR       1A           2ABcR1A
2A     BcR       1A           2ABcR1A
2A     AcR       1A           2AAcR1A
```

For hierarchy, Imagine something like this -

1. BU - Grand Parent
2. RevDes - Parent
3. Rev - Child

**First Step – Calculate the distinct count of the concatenated output column**

For Business Unit, 1A – it will be 3

For Business Unit 2A – it will be  2

**Second Step - check whether Rev Des – FAppR is present for a business unit.**

FAppR is present for Business Unit 1A - so it becomes 1.

FAppR is not present for Business Unit 2A - so it stays the same - 2.

**Final output :-**

So the final output when both business units 1A and 2A are selected is 1 + 2 = 3.

The total output expected is **3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the concatenated column. You can do this with two measures:

```
UniqueCount = 
IF ( 
    COUNTROWS ( 
        FILTER ( 
            Table1, 
            Table1[Rev] = "FAppR"
        )
    ) > 0,
    1,
    COUNTROWS ( 
        GROUPBY ( 
            Table1,
            Table1[BU],
            Table1[Rev],
            Table1[RevDes]
        )
    )
)
```

and

```
UniqueSum = 
SUMX ( 
    DISTINCT ( Table1[BU] ),
    [UniqueCount]
)
```

Use the `UniqueSum` measure for your required output.

Worked example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_54693457/